# How to add batch constraint to an optimization problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have one variable called OS which is the number of orders.
And I have a variable `nt` which is the number of trucks.

And 20 orders can fit into one truck.
I am not sure how to set this up this constraint.
I want to return the number of truck I would need
For example
20 order=2 trucks
25 orders=3 trucks

I did
`os[i]==10*nt[i]`
where `nt` is the number of trucks but this does not seem to work.

```
for i in range(0,364):
    constraintTruckload=os[i]==(nt[i]*10)
    k4.append(constraintTruckload)
for i in range(0,364):
   model+=k4[i]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want at most $10$ orders per truck, the constraint is $\text{os} \le 10 \text{nt}$.  You would need to declare $\text{nt}$ (and presumably also $\text{os}$) as an integer variable. If there are no other constraints on the trucks, the minimum number of trucks would then be $\text{nt}=\lceil\text{os}/10\rceil$, but this is not a linear constraint.